# TestNG reporting dynamic test cases

Tags: testng, testcase, test-report

I have multiple Test Cases using a single test method dynamically.

It it possible for TestNG to report the number of passed Test Cases and number of failed Test Cases?

If it is possible, how do I do this?

Comment: Unclear what you're asking, please modify your question with some examples or screens.

Comment: Not sure I understand you correctly, but are you putting multiple tests into a single test? And you expect the reporter to split them into single test results? Every test should have its own test-method. Just split them up.

Comment: Please reformat your question so it is clear what is context and what you want to achieve and then a question. Currently there is not a clear question.

Comment: Reworded to clarify - if I am wrong, please revert.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the TestNG reporter shows this info in the results by default. The screenshots in [this TestNG reporting howto](https://examples.javacodegeeks.com/enterprise-java/testng/testng-html-xml-reports-example/) shows: Total methods, failed and passed.

Alternatively let a [CI-server](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous_integration) (like the free [teamcity](https://www.jetbrains.com/teamcity/) or open-source [jenkins](https://jenkins.io/)) report and mail results. You do have a build server which runs the tests on each commit, don't you? :)

We are using TeamCity where the result (as I write this) looks like this:

[image]

Hmm need to fix some tests...